# save post url as a session name?

Tags: php, url, session, cookies, background

I am developing a custom homepage background,in my html have

```
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
<input type="text" width="128px" name="mybg">
<input type="submit" value="Set as background">
</form>

<b style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;background:url('<?=$_SESSION['mybg'];?>');"></b>
```

and my php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['mybg'])){
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 7);
session_start();
$_SESSION['mybg'] = $_GET['mybg'];
}
```

and my background image shown as post url,the url like `"http://si.te/?mybg=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fpic.jpg"` but when i go back to the homepage(index.php) and the background image disappeared,how can I save that in the session?

I don't want to use any sql please do not suggest that.

Comment: Register you session mybg using session_register() function and check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mainly correct, but you have to move the `session_start()` outside the `if` condition. If you don't, the session will not be started when you go back to your homepage, and `$_SESSION['mybg']` will not be set.

Comment: okay..i tried,but still haven't background image when url didn't have ?selfbg=

Answer (score 0):

replace your html form tag line with below and try..

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Comment: sorry for the misunderstatinding,the form part is inside a php echo fuction

Comment: its ok, session_start(); add top of the page and try

Answer (score 0):

this line is define to top of your page

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 7);
session_start();
```